# Reading in from csv.parse() in d3.js is not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This works:

```
var test=d3.csv("ford.csv");
console.log("test: "+test);
```

This returns empty:

```
var testA=d3.csv.parse("ford.csv");
console.log("testA: "+testA);
```

This is a visual of the console log:

[image]

I'm using version 3.5.5, any ideas what's going on here?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d3.csv` is a asysnc method, it takes an **http path** to a csv file and returns an object immediately.  When it completes if fires a callback argument.  It's usually used as:

```
  d3.csv('ford.csv',function(data){
    console.log(data);
  })

  [Object, Object]
  0: Object
     Length: "2.34"
     Make: "Ford"
     Model: "E350"
     Year: "1997"
```

`d3.csv.parse` takes a **string**.  It parses it and returns an array of objects:

```
console.log(d3.csv.parse("Year,Make,Model,Length\n1997,Ford,E350,2.34\n2000,Mercury,Cougar,2.38"))

  [Object, Object]
  0: Object
     Length: "2.34"
     Make: "Ford"
     Model: "E350"
     Year: "1997"
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about that, I did read the docs and somehow it didn't register. Sorry man. You can delete or close this question as dumb if you want to. No harm no foul, ok?

Answer (score 4):

Your first example takes a file by it's filename and parses the csv file. The second example takes a string of the CONTENTS of the file and parses them. For example,

```
d3.csv("filename.csv", function(){...});
```

vs.

```
d3.csv.parse("Red, Green, Yellow\nApple, Pear, Lemon...");
```

Comment: Sorry to waste your time bro, it was in the docs as clear as day. I completely missed it.

Comment: no worries. and no question is too dumb. No one is expected to retain everything from the docs, that's why they exist in the first place :)